# How to publish/deploy visual studio project as an installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, installation, publish

I just finished developing a system for a company. It will be used on 50+ PCs.

The only problem left is the installation process. I don't think it's efficient to manually copy the whole folder of the project e.g. on Documents folder and create a Desktop shortcut of the .exe file on every PC.

If possible, I'd like to compress *(not sure if this is the right term for it)* the whole project folder into a single setup/installer which will place it in the Documents folder and create a Desktop shortcut of the .exe file. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all install this.left

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Once you have this installed,

go to Solution Explorer and right click "Solution "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME" go down to "Add" and select "New Project" on the right hand side scroll down to "Other Project Type" and expend it and click on "Visual Studio Installer" and select "Setup Project" and Name your setup exe.

A new window will pop up. On the left hand side you will see "Application Folder" Right click on it and select "Add" > "Project output" and click on "Primary Output" and press "ok"

Once you have done that, on the right hand side you should see two or more files, right click on the one that should say "Primary output From "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME" and select "create Shortcut - "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME"

Once that is done, rename your shortcut to your programs name. eg "my first program" after that click and drag it to "Users Desktop Folder on the left hand side.

Then right click "User's Program Menu" and add a Folder and name it to your programs company name "eg Microsoft" this will make a folder in the start menu.

After that select the folder you have just renamed and right click on the right hand side and select "Create new Shortcut" a window will pop up for you, select the "Application Folder" and then "Primary output from YOUR PROGRAMS NAME" and press "ok"

Once all of this is done close out of it and go to "Solution Explorer" and press F4, here you will have the options to add details about your program eg who it is and even an icon.

I may have missed somethings, but after reading this you will have a basic idea of what is required and you will be able to add your own things.

Also i cant remember but you might have to also add your programs Icon to the "Application Folder"

once you have done everything, open "solution explorer" and right click on the new project you have created and press "build" you will be able to find the files where you main project is located.

Good Luck!

Comment: I was immediately lost. Can't seem to find "Other Project Type". http://imgur.com/a/dU9Ea
sorry, this is my first time deploying a project.

Comment: Within your project, do to add new item

Comment: Austin:Other Project type is at the bottom of the image you posted.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. They (the company) said that it's okay to manually copy paste the whole project folder on each PC. It's been 2 days since they started using it, and there are no problems arising so far.

In the meantime, I tried your answer again (btw, thanks @PhilDW ) and the build succeeded. I noticed a new folder inside the project folder named "SETUP_ScanCheckSystem" (I named the setup.exe as that). Ok, so I tried to run the setup file but was met with this http://imgur.com/a/WLDbx window. How should I proceed? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Setup Project

[MSDN Setup Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: This creates a new project. I already have an existing one. "To add an existing setup project to a solution" gives an error: The project cannot be added to the solution because it is already a member of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Wix Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) to create an installer in the past. It's a bit of a learning curve, but once you get the hang of it, I think its pretty good. It will let you manage install location, desktop and start menu shortcuts etc, and install any software dependencies such as a particular .NET framework version or Adobe Reader for instance. There is also an extension for visual studio and its free which always helps.

Comment: Hi, I'll try @Werdna's answer first before this one. Thanks for the suggestion.