# Visual studio project installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make installation for my Visual Studio project, but I want everything to be packed in one .exe file, so that, when I want to send it to someone to install it, everything I send is that .exe file.

I've tried using Visual Studio Installer Project, and it made me a working installation, but for it, I need to share other project files in order to make it work.

I expect to be able to share only installation file with other computers, not to be in need to share other project files in order to make it work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38656770/how-to-publish-deploy-visual-studio-project-as-an-installer/38657333#38657333  Although this is for vb, it should be the same.

Comment: If you made installation project no need to publish project files, you will only publish your setup files

Comment: Inno Setup is nice